# drop down menu bootstrap doesn't work in tablet android

Tags: android, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i work with Bootstrap V3.1.1, my application looks fine in my PC, but when i try it on an Android tablet, then my drop down menu doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group">                           
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Inserer lien site mobile</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 <span class="caret"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu accordéon version site1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu accordéon version site2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu accordéon version site3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser?  I had trouble with a lot of bootstrap components on the default browser, but running chrome on my android device solved these problems.

Comment: I have the same problem. @Mohammadov how did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you integrated all required css & jquery?

Maybe you check out the examples: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples on the browser. If they work, you got someting wrong.